# AADSTS70001: Application '574c1791-d632-4180-91e4-38094a8a3a77' is not supported for this API version

Tags: asp.net, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, office365api

I am trying to use office365 api in my single page .net application not an mvc. I got the source code for mvc .net project C# in the website itself.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn()
            {
                string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]; 
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

                // The url in our app that Azure should redirect to after successful signin
                Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));

                // Generate the parameterized URL for Azure signin
                Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes, null, clientId, redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

                // Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page

                return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
            }



         // Note the function signature is changed!
                public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize()
                {
                    // Get the 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect
                    string authCode = Request.Params["code"];

                    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]; ;
                    string clientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]; ;
                    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

                    // The same url we specified in the auth code request
                    Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));

                    // Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
                    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get the token
                        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                            authCode, redirectUri, credential, scopes);

                        // Save the token in the session
                        Session["access_token"] = authResult.Token;

                        // Try to get user info
                        Session["user_email"] = GetUserEmail(authContext, clientId);

                        return Redirect(Url.Action("Inbox", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));
                    }
                    catch (AdalException ex)
                    {
                        return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
                    }
                }
```

I converted the code to vb.net and i am receiving bad request error stating that my application is not supported for this api version when executed. The code is in WebForm1.aspx and the redirect uri link is to webform2.aspx

```
Private Sub SignIn()

            Dim authority As String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
            Dim clientId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientID")
            Dim authContext As New AuthenticationContext(authority)
            Dim redirectUri As New Uri("http://localhost:26683/WebForm2.aspx")

            Dim authUri As Uri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL("https://outlook.office.com/mail.read", clientId, redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, Nothing)
            Response.Redirect(authUri.ToString())    

        End Sub
```

How ever i have registered the application.In fact when i used the same client id  and client secret for the mvc application it is executed without any error but when i use it in my single web application it throws this error.
Please help.What am i doing wrong

Comment: make sure that both applications have the same return url. VS by default will assign a different port for each web app.

Comment: both the application has the same local host url